# PHP jQuery Form Submission

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I've built a simple form which I want to send without refreshing the page, therefore I use jQuery. The problem comes up when I submit the form but process.php reports that the data was not transformed, and process.php prints the message "no post received".
Here's the code of the form file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1255">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
      $('#submit').click(function(){
          var getField = $("#field").val();
          $.ajax({
             url: 'process.php' , 
             type: 'POST',
             data: 'data: ' + getField,
             success: function(result){     
               $('#container').text('<p>' + result + '</p>')      
             }
          });   
          return false;     
       });
    });
</script>

<body>

<div id="container">
<form method="post" action="process.php">
<input name="field" id="field" type="text" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit" />
</form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's process.php code :

```
<?php
if($_POST){
    echo $_POST['field'];
}
else
    echo "no post received";
?>
```

Do you have any idea what's wrong with the jQuery / the form ?
Any suggestion is welcomed, 
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your `data` isn't formatted correctly. It should be a complete JavaScript object:

```
data: '{ data: "' + getField + '"}',
```

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#entry-examples

Alternatively, and more conveniently, try using the [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method.

Comment: Actually, I think he needs to submit the actual object: data: { data: getField},

Answer (score 0):

```
data: 'data: ' + getField
```

That's posting the value of getField to process.php as "data", not "field", so you need to get the value of $_POST['data'], although naming variables "data" is usually not a good idea. You might also want to look up the jQuery post function, which was made for exactly what you're doing.